# Binding error in hidden toolbar

Tags: c#, wpf, toolbar

I have next xaml:

```
<ToolbarTray Visibility="{Binding SomeProperty}">
    <Toolbar>
       <Checkbox IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}/"
        <... other items />
    </Toolbar>
</Toolbar>
```

and two classes as possible data context - for two different windows.

```
 class ToolbarContextOne
 {
     public Visibility SomeProperty {get;set;}
 }

 class ToolbarContextTwo:ToolbarContextOne
 {
     public bool IsEnabled {get;set;}
 }
```

I hide toolbartray from example when I don't need it. But even if SomeProperty set to Visibility.Collapsed, I still getting binding errors for IsEnabled option when I use ToolbarContextOne as data context.
I suspect it happens because it is how parser works. But maybe there is a way I can avoid this issue without my data context classes change?

Comment: what's the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to avoid the binding errors is to use `FallbackValue` in binding:

```
<ToolbarTray Visibility="{Binding SomeProperty}">
    <Toolbar>
       <Checkbox IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, FallbackValue=False}/"
        <... other items />
    </Toolbar>
</Toolbar>
```

**Updated**
Another way would be to enable binding only when DataContext has specific property:

```
<CheckBox>
    <CheckBox.Resources>
        <local:HasPropertyConverter x:Key="HasPropertyConverter"/>
    </CheckBox.Resources>
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=.,Converter={StaticResource HasPropertyConverter},
                                                      ConverterParameter=IsEnabled}"
                             Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

and converter:

```
public class HasPropertyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (parameter == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        PropertyInfo property = value.GetType().GetProperty(parameter.ToString());
        return property != null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Is that binding error so much important except for the developer ?**

The bindings error are only visble in the debugging output windows, aren't they ?

The user can't see the toolbartay after all.

**If the error is really annoying, you can either :**

1 Provide a ToolbarContextTwo for the Datacontext.

2 Add the IsEnbled property to ToolbarContextOne

Regards

Comment: Of course I can, I know how to fix issue with context refactoring. I want to avoid that way.

Comment: Sorry to have a "closed" answer but I want to answer your question, and I think there is no other way